# how to displace a mesh (in viewport) with a texture without changing the vertex normals direction?

Tags: 3d-view, export, vertices, normals, displacement

I'm trying to displace a geometry while keeping the original vertex normal's direction, I need the effect to be achieved in viewport since the mesh must be exported into a game engine.

The only way I found at the moment is by  using a -Data Transfer modifier- which has the intended effect but it's VERY heavy and can create artifacts.
I wonder if with Geometry nodes it would be possible to achieve the same effect by freezing in some way the vertex normal direction.
Any hint will be highly appreciated.

Thank you~

[image: comparison between displacement and displacement + data transfer modifier]

Comment: Just to eliminate the possibility of [XY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), Can we ask _why_ you want to do this? (If the appearance remains as it was before displacement, why displace?)

Comment: Because the Vertex Normal is defined by the normal map, this is how Displacement works in ue5 or substance designer for example.
If the geometry generates the normals,the normal map will result too strong since it will be added by the normal of the displaced geometry.